# how to iterate json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have an json array

```
$response5 = $tracking->info('ups','1ZA74Y990304232598',array('title','order_id'));


Array
(
    [meta] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [tracking] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 55a3a81a3398c2e12f2dc9af
                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T11:59:22+00:00
                    [updated_at] => 2015-07-13T14:59:23+00:00
                    [last_updated_at] => 2015-07-13T14:59:23+00:00
                    [tracking_number] => 1ZA74Y990304232598
                    [slug] => ups
                    [active] => 1
                    [android] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [custom_fields] => 
                    [customer_name] => 
                    [delivery_time] => 4
                    [destination_country_iso3] => USA
                    [emails] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [expected_delivery] => 2015-07-16
                    [ios] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [note] => 
                    [order_id] => 
                    [order_id_path] => 
                    [origin_country_iso3] => USA
                    [shipment_package_count] => 1
                    [shipment_pickup_date] => 2015-07-08T16:00:00
                    [shipment_delivery_date] => 
                    [shipment_type] => GROUND
                    [shipment_weight] => 4.6
                    [shipment_weight_unit] => lb
                    [signed_by] => 
                    [smses] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [source] => api
                    [tag] => InTransit
                    [title] => 1ZA74Y990304232598
                    [tracked_count] => 2
                    [unique_token] => b16qZz90fg
                    [checkpoints] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [slug] => ups
                                    [city] => 
                                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T11:59:23+00:00
                                    [location] => US
                                    [country_name] => US
                                    [message] => BILLING INFORMATION RECEIVED
                                    [country_iso3] => USA
                                    [tag] => InfoReceived
                                    [checkpoint_time] => 2015-07-09T18:21:16
                                    [coordinates] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [state] => 
                                    [zip] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [slug] => ups
                                    [city] => OBETZ
                                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T11:59:23+00:00
                                    [location] => OBETZ, OH, US
                                    [country_name] => OBETZ, OH, US
                                    [message] => ORIGIN SCAN
                                    [country_iso3] => USA
                                    [tag] => InTransit
                                    [checkpoint_time] => 2015-07-10T20:41:00
                                    [coordinates] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [state] => OH
                                    [zip] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [slug] => ups
                                    [city] => OBETZ
                                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T11:59:23+00:00
                                    [location] => OBETZ, OH, US
                                    [country_name] => OBETZ, OH, US
                                    [message] => DEPARTURE SCAN
                                    [country_iso3] => USA
                                    [tag] => InTransit
                                    [checkpoint_time] => 2015-07-10T21:58:00
                                    [coordinates] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [state] => OH
                                    [zip] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [slug] => ups
                                    [city] => INDIANAPOLIS
                                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T11:59:23+00:00
                                    [location] => INDIANAPOLIS, IN, US
                                    [country_name] => INDIANAPOLIS, IN, US
                                    [message] => ARRIVAL SCAN
                                    [country_iso3] => USA
                                    [tag] => InTransit
                                    [checkpoint_time] => 2015-07-11T01:36:00
                                    [coordinates] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [state] => IN
                                    [zip] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [slug] => ups
                                    [city] => INDIANAPOLIS
                                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T11:59:23+00:00
                                    [location] => INDIANAPOLIS, IN, US
                                    [country_name] => INDIANAPOLIS, IN, US
                                    [message] => DEPARTURE SCAN
                                    [country_iso3] => USA
                                    [tag] => InTransit
                                    [checkpoint_time] => 2015-07-11T04:25:00
                                    [coordinates] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [state] => IN
                                    [zip] => 
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [slug] => ups
                                    [city] => HODGKINS
                                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T11:59:23+00:00
                                    [location] => HODGKINS, IL, US
                                    [country_name] => HODGKINS, IL, US
                                    [message] => ARRIVAL SCAN
                                    [country_iso3] => USA
                                    [tag] => InTransit
                                    [checkpoint_time] => 2015-07-11T07:23:00
                                    [coordinates] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [state] => IL
                                    [zip] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [slug] => ups
                                    [city] => HODGKINS
                                    [created_at] => 2015-07-13T14:59:23+00:00
                                    [location] => HODGKINS, IL, US
                                    [country_name] => HODGKINS, IL, US
                                    [message] => DEPARTURE SCAN
                                    [country_iso3] => USA
                                    [tag] => InTransit
                                    [checkpoint_time] => 2015-07-13T09:25:00
                                    [coordinates] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [state] => IL
                                    [zip] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [tracking_account_number] => 
                    [tracking_destination_country] => 
                    [tracking_key] => 
                    [tracking_postal_code] => 
                    [tracking_ship_date] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I am using aftership api here to display the tracking details of a courier .

I need to loop the checkpoint array here and display all the tracking stages.

How to loop it .

I tried something like the below .

```
  <table style="border: 1px solid #CC9933;margin-top:50px;">
    <tr>
        <th class="porders">Date</th>
        <th class="porders">Location</th>
        <th class="porders">Status</th>
        <tr>
     <?php


     for($i=0; $i<count($response5['data']['tracking']['checkpoints']); $i++) {

        echo "<td class=porders>$response5['data']['tracking']['checkpoints'][$i]['created_at']."</td>";
        echo "<td class=porders>$response5['data']['tracking']['checkpoints'][$i]['country_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td class=porders>$response5['data']['tracking']['checkpoints'][$i]['message']."</td>";
    }
     ?>   


    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: you don't iterate a "json array". you take  json string, decode it to a native data structure, then iterate THAT. and once it's decoded to native, it's not different than any OTHER array/object/whatever.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? You could also use `foreach` instead your `for` block.

Comment: its not getting iterated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php

    foreach ($response5['data']['tracking']['checkpoints'] as $key => $checkpoint) {//as key and value


        echo '<td class="porders">'.$checkpoint['created_at'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="porders">'.$checkpoint['country_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="porders">'.$checkpoint['message'].'</td>';

}

     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `$obj` is already a decoded array, so there is no need to use the `$response5` variable (unless you really want to use it as text).

As for iterating it would look like this:

```
foreach ($obj['data']['tracking']['checkpoints'] as $key => $checkpoint) {
    foreach($checkpoint as $nodeName => $value) {
        echo '<td class="orders">'.$nodeName.' => '.$value.'</td>;
    }
}
```

In order to list your coordinates you would need to run foreach on that node again

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode to move the data to a PHP array.

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

$my_array = json_decode($json);
foreach ($my_array as $element) {
    print $element . " , ";
}
var_dump($my_array);
?>
```

Comment: The OP's data is already in a PHP array, he's asking how to iterate through it.